# Office 2016 applications (Word, Excel, Outlook) will not start

Tags: microsoft-office

It seems to me like that out of the blue sky Office applications started to failing it's start. They look like start to open but nothing happened. If I started it with run as administrator everything was OK.
This behavior might be consequence of VS 2017 installation.

Answer (score 1):

I reapplied read&execute permissions for my user to folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office` and everything was fine.